# Spring mvc 3 general Controller architecture question

Tags: spring-mvc

Sorry for the newbie question,
The scenario is simple, I go Jsp page where one can fill Driver information,
I have setup method for the driver object

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView setUpForm(){
ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("/driverForm");
Driver = myService.getDriver();
modelAndView.addObject("driver",driver);
return modelAndView;
}
```

And update method to get the driver updated data

```
@RequestMapping(params = "update", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
  public String update(Driver driver, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
myService.saveDriver(driver);
return "driversList";
}
```

Then I am "feeding" the jsp layer with the desired driver information, for example driver name:

```
<form:input path="name" size="20" maxlength="50"  />
```

My question is how to populate different model attributes and connect the driver information to these attribute
For example: 
Display various license types as checkboxes for the user to select from (bike,bus,cab, etc) and map them in my controller to a single attribute on the driver object,
Also map the selection when editing existing driver from this field
What is the correct controller architecture?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller add a collection to the model containing all the options you want to offer and then use the from:radioButtons tag to render it so the code would look like this :

```
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView setUpForm(){
ModelAndView modelAndView =  new ModelAndView("/driverForm");
Driver = myService.getDriver();
modelAndView.addObject("driver",driver);
Collection transportType = ....
modelAndView.addObject("transportType", transportType);
return modelAndView;
}
```

In the JSP you would then do something like this

```
<form:radioBoxes items="${transportType}" path="..."/>
```

You can find more information on the radio buttons tag here : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-radiobuttonstag